# Path Forwarding with cloaking or masking

Tags: domain-forwarding, masking, cloaking, path

I have recently developed a website that allows users to have a sub-domain creation of our online store: www.USERNAME.example.com

I need to offer the user the ability to have their own complete domain. www.USERNAME.com and then using cloaking alone with Path Forwarding replace their subdomain:

www.USERNAME.com  == SHOWS INSTEAD OF ==>> www.USERNAME.example.com
www.USERNAME.com/contact === SHOWS INSTEAD OF ==>> www.USERNAME.example.com/contact

I need to know the best way to do this.. I know that each actual domain I will need to purchase.. but does anyone know what coding to add to the htaccess file..

Please include full instructions if possible as I'm not the best at all of this?

Comment: What you want to do can be done with a CNAME (alias) in your DNS.